# Disable annotation processing, but enable web-fragments feature in servlet api 3.0 (Tomcat7)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I am giving a try on Tomcat 7.0 and Servlet API 3.0.

I had an application for Servlet API 2.5. So I edited web.xml to configure it for Servlet API 3.0. After the change the start time of Tomcat increased by 14 seconds.

So I set `<web-app metadata-complete="true" ...` and the start time of Tomcat got back to normal, because tomcat does not scan every class for annotations. This is good, but web-fragment.xml feature is also disabled by this.

I wonder if it possible to disable annotation scanning of Tomcat, but to enable processing of web-fragment.xml.

Comment: increased by 14 seconds to how much? If it's starting 3 minutes, 14 seconds are fine.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using 'absolute-ordering' element in your web.xml.
Servlet API 3.0 Final Spec describes it's usage in section 8.2.2 "Ordering of web.xml and web-fragment.xml".

You can specify **the exact** web-fragments to be processed, disable annotations processing of classes in web-fragment's jar ('metadata-complete' in the web-fragment from the list) and of course exclude other jars from processing by this kind of web-fragment inclusion.

Answer (score 4):

Both fragments and annotations are metadata of the application. **Thus metadata-complete applies for both annotation processing and processing of fragments.** 
If the **metadata-complete is set for web.xml, both the annotation processing and fragments processing are disabled**.

But, the metadata-complete can also be set to web-fragments.xml. So, one can do selective processing of annotations and fragments.

**Enabling metadata-complete on web.xml and disabling on web-fragments.xml will process fragments but disables the annotation processing of classes under web-fragments.xml**

Comment: I tested it, it doesn't seem to work in Tomcat 7.0.22. By the way, i'm not quite understand, if I enable metadata-complete on web.xml, application server will skip the annotation processing and fragments processing all together. In this case, how could the configuration in web-fragments.xml work? It cannot be even parsed, right?

Comment: You should not set metadata-complete on web.xml. It will disable web fragments as well as annotation processing. You should enable it on web-fragments.xml. Please Read the answer carefully.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, thanks for your quick replay. I've just testet, set metadata-complete to false (or just take the default value) on web.xml and set metadata-complete to true on web-fragment.xml will make Tomcat skip the annotation processing, but only for that web-fragment jar, right? Does Tomcat still scan other jars under WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Yes it will just skip annotation processing and considers the web-fragment.xml entries.